# How to add a hidden column to display filter values in the dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am using datatables from my project and it works great. However I am running into a problem with column filtering.

Position column has too long values.
Using select.append( ''+d.substring(0,15)+'' ); doesn't work as I want the text to be different for each value.

Is there a way to use a hidden column with simple text to display for filtering so that I dont run into this? So

System Architectghhghjjkjukjkj

for example would look Sys Architect in the column filter.

Link to my code - https://live.datatables.net/clone/7735/edit

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    searching: true
  });

  buildSelect(table);
 
  table.on('draw', function() {
    buildSelect(table);
  });
  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
  });
});

function buildSelect(table) {
  var counter = 0;
  table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
    var column = table.column(this, {
      search: 'applied'
    });
    counter++;
    var select = $('<select><option value="">select me</option></select>')
      .appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );

        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
      select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d.substring(0,15)+'</option>' );
    });

    // The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
    var currSearch = column.search();
    if (currSearch) {
      // ** MY CHANGE **
      // Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
      // This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
      select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<div class="searchbox">
<p>Name: 
  
  <span id="dropdown1">
  </span>
</p>

<p>Postion: <span id="dropdown2">
  </span>
</p>

<p>Office: <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
</p>
  <button type="button" id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
  <table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;"><thead>
<tr>

<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
</tr>


          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>ID.AI</td>
            <td><p>System Architectghhghjjkjukjkj<p></td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett -2</td>
            <td><p>Director fgghghjhjhjhkjkj<p></td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton.1 -2</td>
            <td><p>Technical Authorjkjkjk fdfd h gjjjhjhk<p></td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          
            
          </tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```